# Microsoft Edge extension weird behaviour

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

I have a Microsoft Edge extension which blocks specific URLs and redirect the browser to another page where the user click a button and it redirects back to the original page.
The extension sends the original URL in the redirection URL and it is used when the target page redirect back to it.
My problem, sometime the original page sends not its own URL but a jpg image on it. It happens when the original page load a bit slowly in the browser.

I don't understand this error.

```
//background.js
const apps = [    
  ['ABCD', 'abcd']
];
const triggerUrls = [
  "http://abcd/*"
];  

function logURL(requestDetails) {
const domain = (new URL(requestDetails.url)).hostname.replace('www.','').toLowerCase();
const partDomain = apps.findIndex(u => domain.toUpperCase().split('.')[0].includes(u[0]));
chrome.cookies.get({ 'url': requestDetails.url.toLowerCase(), 'name': 'status' }, 
    function(data){         
        if (data === null) {                                
            if (partDomain > -1) {
                chrome.cookies.set({
                    url: requestDetails.url.toLowerCase(),
                    name: "status",
                    value: "opened"
                });
                var backUrl = requestDetails.url;
                const url = 'http://warning.xx/?title=' + apps[partDomain][0] + '&url=' + backUrl;
                chrome.tabs.update( requestDetails.tabId, { url: url} );
            }
        }
    }   
);  
}
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  logURL,
  {urls: triggerUrls},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: I would suggest also trying to check the issue in the Google Chrome browser. See whether you could reproduce the same issue. If it is reproducible then you could check what actually happens when the page gets loaded slowly. Maybe some elements are not loaded yet or the JS code was executed late, etc. You could inform us how exactly your extension fetches the original URL from that web page? Is possible for you to check whether there is an extension at the end of the URL? It may help to validate the URL.

Comment: I tried to fix the problem by filtering out URLs which are not relevant about the task. For example which end with .jpg, .ico, etc. extensions in URLs. Now it is on test.

Comment: it is great to know that filtering the URLs helped to avoid the issue. After you finish your tests, you could try to post the detailed answer to your own question and mark it as an answer whenever it is available to accept as an answer. It may help other community members in the future with similar issues. Thanks for your understanding.